# How to typecast integer to unsigned in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to divide two integers as following:

```vhdl
variable m0Low : integer := 0;
variable m1Low : integer := 0;
m1Low := divide(m1Low,m0Low);
```

With the  function :

```vhdl
function  divide  (a : UNSIGNED; b : UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED is    
    variable a1 : unsigned(a'length-1 downto 0):=a;    
    variable b1 : unsigned(b'length-1 downto 0):=b;    
    variable p1 : unsigned(b'length downto 0):= (others => '0');    
    variable i : integer:=0;               
    begin    
        for i in 0 to b'length-1 loop    
            p1(b'length-1 downto 1) := p1(b'length-2 downto 0);    
            p1(0) := a1(a'length-1);    
            a1(a'length-1 downto 1) := a1(a'length-2 downto 0);    
            p1 := p1-b1;    
            if(p1(b'length-1) ='1') then    
                a1(0) :='0';    
                p1 := p1+b1;    
            else    
                a1(0) :='1';    
            end if;
        end loop;    
    return a1;    
end divide;
```

However, I get the following error:
`Divide can not have such operands in this context.`

I am trying to cast the variables to unsigned `m1Low := divide(unsigned(m1Low),unsigned(m0Low));`

But I get the following error:
`The expression can not be converted to type unsigned.`

Any idea what I can do? 
Thanks
Haris

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the divide operator? `m1Low := M1Low/m0Low`?

Comment: It gives the error that the right part of the / sign must be a power of 2 ! No idea why.

Comment: Ahh, that's because your synthesizer is not clever enough to build a divider for non-static, non-powers-of-2.  Evaluating better (ie more expensive ;() synthesis-tools might help.  Or using CoreGen to build a divider core.

Answer (score 7):

To convert integer to unsigned or signed data type over,

```
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
```

you must use,

```
to_unsigned(I,U’length);
to_signed(I,S’length)
```

where I is the integer value and U'length is the unsigned vector length ( the number of bit ).

I didn't verify your code and how it's actually working but my correction on your code is just,

```
m1Low := to_integer(divide(to_unsigned(m1Low, N),to_unsigned(m0Low, N)));
```

you should specify N where its the length of your vector depend on your design. I used to_integer() because your function is returning unsigned value to integer variable.

Hope this simple notes help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass integers as unsigned vectors, you need to *convert* them, not *typecast* them.

First you want the `numeric_std` library:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Then you can use `to_unsigned` to convert the integers to unsigned vectors.  For that function you need to know the length of the unsigned vector you are converting to so use the `'length` attribute:

```
destination_vector := to_unsigned(source_integer, destination_vector'length);
```

You can convert back from unsigned to integer (which doesn't need to be told the length of the input, as information about function inputs is directly available to the function) like this:

```
destination_integer := to_integer(source_vector);
```